# Can I call different methods on a button based on the value of a boolean property in the HTML code of an Angular component?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

I am working on an Angular project and I have the following behavior to implement. Into the HTML code of my component I have a button that clicked should have a different behavior based on the value of an async proerty boolean value.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container py-4" *ngIf="!(isMobile | async); else mobile">
    <div class="card" id="toolbar-card">
        <div class="toolbar-container">
            {{isMobile | async}}
            <div class="row">
                <div id="toolbar-left" class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-start">
                    <button pButton pRipple label="New" icon="pi pi-plus" class="p-button-success p-mr-2"
                        (click)="showNewPatientDialog()">
                    </button>

                    <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-trash" class="p-button-danger centered-icon"></button>
                </div>
                <div id="toolbar-right" class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <!--<p-fileUpload mode="basic" accept="image/*" [maxFileSize]="1000000" label="Import" chooseLabel="Import" class="p-mr-2 p-d-inline-block"></p-fileUpload>-->
                    <button type="button" pButton pRipple label="Export" icon="pi pi-file-excel"
                        class="p-button-success p-mr-2" pTooltip="XLS" tooltipPosition="bottom"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- TOOLBAR -->
```

As you can see by this **{{isMobile | async}}** I can print out the value that can be only true or false (it works fine).

At the moment I have this **New** button:

```
<button pButton pRipple label="New" icon="pi pi-plus" class="p-button-success p-mr-2"
        (click)="showNewPatientDialog()">
</button>
```

As you can see this button at the moment have a single behavior: it calls the **showNewPatientDialog()** method.

I know that I can use **ngIf** directive to show this button if the value of **isMobile** is false and another **button** tag if it is true.

But is it possible to use the same button and simply call two different methods bsed on the value of my **isMobile** property?

**EDIT-1:** I am trying in this way:

```
<button pButton pRipple label="New" icon="pi pi-plus" class="p-button-success p-mr-2"
                            (click)="(isMobile | async) ? showNewPatientDialog() : showNewPatientDesktopComponent()">
                    </button>
```

I can not simply use **isMobile** variable because it is a **BehaviorSubject** object so I have to retrieve it with **async** pipe so this will not work correctly:

```
<button pButton pRipple label="New" icon="pi pi-plus" class="p-button-success p-mr-2"
        (click)="isMobile ? showNewPatientDialog() : theOtherMethod()">
</button>

Using **(click)="(isMobile | async)** I obtain the following error in compilation:

 src/app/features/patient/patients-list/patients-list.component.ts:12:16
    12   templateUrl: './patients-list.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component PatientsListComponent.
src/app/features/patient/patients-list/patients-list.component.html:155:56 - error NG5002: Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 13 in [(isMobile | async) ? showNewPatientDialog() : showNewPatientDesktopComponent()] in /home/andrea/Documenti/Angular-WS/gestionale-medico-portal/src/app/features/patient/patients-list/patients-list.component.html@19:37

155                 <button pButton type="button" (click)="showNewPatientDialog()" icon="pi pi-plus"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution which is tested successfully.
1st of all isMobile var is bool you make it as number with defualt value 0.
Now if it's mobile assign 1 to isMobile or else 2.
hide button if isMobile is 0 or show another same button.
follow the code

```
//app.component.html
<button
#btn1
id="btn1"
(click)="isMobile == 1 ? toggle(btn1) : toggle2(btn1)"
class="someclass"
*ngIf="isMobile"
>
 Button
</button>  

//app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
 name = 'Angular';
 buttonValue: string;
 isMobile = 0; 

 ngOnInit() {
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(async function () {
      await that.getIsMobile().then((result) => {
        that.isMobile = result
      });
      console.log('inside', that.isMobile);
    }, 3000);
 }
 toggle(button) {
    console.log('toggle1');
 }
 toggle2(button) {
    console.log('toggle2');
 }
 getIsMobile() {
   return new Promise<Number>((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(2);
    })
 }
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-click-gg49yx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition inside the click event to determine what method should be called, for example:

```
<button pButton pRipple label="New" icon="pi pi-plus" class="p-button-success p-mr-2"
        (click)="isMobile ? showNewPatientDialog() : theOtherMethod()">
</button>
```

Comment: In this way doesn't work because I have to retrieve the isMobile in async way, I added some further details at the end of my original post

Comment: You could try either loading the variable in onInit so your template does not have to deal with the async pipe or load a different template when the observable has not returned a result yet, examples here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/

Comment: I know but it is not a solution on my case because I have to handle the case related to the windows screen change...So I need to use this BehaviorSubject